# Why am I getting "Directory not empty" error in terminal when using rmdir?

Tags: shell, command-line, terminal, command-prompt

I am walking through a tutorial and it lets me delete two directories (I'm using one 10 deep, all empty) but once I try to remove the third it gives me that error message, even though there is no content in the directory and I am in the directory above it. Why is this? By the way I am using terminal.

Comment: Go into the directory in question and try typing "ls -a" to see if there are any hidden files or folders (ls -a <directory-name>" would also work).

Comment: Im not sure what this is but this is what that command returned `.  ..  .DS_Store` i am guessing this is a hidden file?

Comment: Correct.  The first two are links to the current directory and one above it respectively, and .DS_Store is a Mac file that has to do with indexing I think.  In any case, you can remove DS_Store safely, and the other two shouldn't cause you problems.

Comment: Please accept the answer (or write an answer of your own and accept that) so that this doesn't show up as unresolved. Thanks.

Comment: I second @tripleee's comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That error is reported when the directory is not empty.

To find out what files are in that directory use `ls -a`. The `-a` flag tells `ls` to list hidden files (aka "dot files"). Remove those files then `rmdir` can be used.

Another option is to simply use `rm -rf` to recursively delete the directory and all of its files. NOTE: this can be dangerous if you give the wrong parameters - resulting in deleting more than you intended.

Comment: don't forget the sudo for most operating systems homie. So that would be sudo rm -rf

Comment: Trying to delete the Library folder from an old drive, this procedure fails.
Thoughts?

guido@iMac guido % ls -rla Library/Application\ Support/icdd
total 0
drwx------  3 guido  staff  102 May 12 09:32 ..
drwx------  3 guido  staff  102 May 12 09:29 .
guido@iMac guido % sudo rmdir !$
sudo rmdir Library/Application\ Support/icdd
rmdir: Library/Application Support/icdd: Directory not empty
guido@iMac guido % paul@Pauls-iMac paul % sudo rm -rf  Library/Application\ Support/icdd rm: Library/Application Support/icdd: Permission denied

Answer (score 2):

you can remove all hidden files by using rm -R ./.*  you have to be in the directory the hidden file is in for it to work

Answer (score -1):

On Windows I recently has the same problem, and deleting everything in `{UserFolder}\AppData\Local\Composer\files` didn't helped.

What I've done is to launch multiple times the `composer install --dry-run` command until it listed all dependencies, then I successfully ran the `composer install` command.